# Reading the content of a file with JavaScript from the server and returning it to the application

Tags: javascript, ajax, server, xmlhttprequest, return

I have a JavaScript function that reads a file from the server. I wanted it to return the result to me, but it doesn't work. The codes are as follows. The alert does not work. what is the reason ? And how can I fix it?

```
function red(filename) {
    let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onload = function() {
    return this.responseText;
    }
    xhttp.open("POST",filename, true);
    xhttp.send();
    }
    
    alert( red("file.txt"));
```

Comment: You might want to read up on [asynchronous calls](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Introducing).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.